# How to catch all request in Webview - Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, webview, xamarin.android, android-webview

Am having a Webview in my Xamarin android project and **am trying to Catch a URL with specific keyword.** If the keyword is present I need to open that link through the normal browser.but the URLoverriding is not getting involked.

```
web_view.Settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
        web_view.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
        web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        web_view.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
        web_view.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
        web_view.Settings.DisplayZoomControls = true;
        web_view.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        web_view.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
        web_view.LoadUrl(URL);
        web_view.SetWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient(this));
```

and this is my **webview client**

```
 public class HelloWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{

    public Activity mActivity;
    public HelloWebViewClient(Activity mActivity)
    {
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
                
    }

    public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
    {
        string link = request.Url.ToString();
        if (link.Contains("Session"))
        {
            return true;

        }
        else
        {
            view.LoadUrl(request.Url.ToString());
            return false;
        }
        
    }

}
```

the URLOverride method is not getting involked, **am I missing something?** Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)) docs :

> Note: This method is not called for POST requests.

> Note: This method may be called for subframes and with non-HTTP(S) schemes; calling WebView#loadUrl(String) with such a URL will fail.

In this scenaio , override [ShouldInterceptRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)) instead .

##### Sample code

```
public override WebResourceResponse ShouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
{
    string link = request.Url.ToString();
    if (link.Contains("Session"))
    {
        return new WebResourceResponse("text/css", "UTF-8", data);
    }
    else
    {
        return base.ShouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
    }        
}
```